# Show, there exists exactly one operator with $\int_A P_T(f)\, d\lambda=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non-singular function, i.e. a measurable function with the property that
> >     $$
> > \forall A\in\mathcal{B}: \lambda(A)=0 \implies \lambda(T^{-1}(A))=0.
> > $$
> >     Show: There exists exactly one linear operator  $P_T\colon L_{\lambda}^1\to L_{\lambda}^1$ so that for all $f\in L_{\lambda}^1$ and all $A\in \mathcal{B}$ it is
> >     $$
> > \int_A P_T(f)\, d\lambda=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda.
> > $$

Hello, I would really prefer to present you my own recent ideas but I do not have own ideas. To be honest, I am rather helpless. Can you pls give me help?

Greetings.

math12

New **Edit**:

The only thing I already know is that

$A\mapsto\int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda$

is a signed measure.

Now one can apply Radon-Nikodým or something like that?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: This operator is commonly called transfer operator, or Perron-Frobenius operator, in ergodic theory. You can find many informations on it using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is
$$
\int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}\, df\lambda=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}\, d\lambda_f=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{T^{-1}(A)}\, d\lambda_f=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_A\circ T\, d\lambda_f \\=\int_{T^{-1}(A)}\chi_A\circ T\, d\lambda_f=\int_A\chi_A\, d\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}=\int_A\, d\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}
$$
(So the function

$$
A\longmapsto\int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda=\int_A \, d\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}
$$
is a measure relating to $\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}$ with density $1$.)

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\lambda(A)=0$.

Then
$$
\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}(A)=f\lambda(T^{-1}(A))=0
$$
by assumption, i.e. $\lambda_f\circ T^{-1}\ll\lambda$.

Now use Radon-Nikodým to determine $P_T(f)$.

And do not forget to show that $P_T$ is linear (using some properties of Radon-Nikod´m-densities you probably know.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the signed measure
$$
  \mu(A)
  =
  \int_{T^{-1}(A)}f\, d\lambda.
$$
AFTER verifying that $\mu$ satisfies the [Radon-Nikodým](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) hypothesis,
use the theorem to find a unique $g$ such that
$$
  \mu(A)
  =
  \int_A g\, d\lambda.
$$
This $g$ is exactly $P_T(f)$.

For the hypotheses, you have to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and that $\mu \ll \lambda$. Let me know if you need help with that.

---

**Edit:**
<del>Contrary to what I have written, you do not need to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. This hypothesis is for $\lambda$. And by the way, $\lambda$ does not have to be Lebesgue. It just has to be $\sigma$-finite for the proof to hold.</del>

It seems that, in order to use the theorem, both measures, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have to be $\sigma$-finite. If you know of a proof of the Radon-Nikodým theorem that does not require $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite, let me know... :-)

But anyway, $\mu$ is not only $\sigma$-finite. It is finite, because $f$ has finite integral. In fact
$$
  |\mu(A)|
  =
  \left|\int_{T^{-1}(A)} f d\lambda\right|
  \leq
  \int_{\mathbb{}} |f| d\lambda
  <
  \infty
$$
Had we missed the hypothesis that $f \in L^1_{\lambda}$? ;-)

Also, $\lambda$ does not have to be Lebesgue. It just has to be $\sigma$-finite for the proof to hold.

Comment: How can I find that g?

Comment: The $g$ is given by the Radon-Nikodým theorem. The conclusion of the theorem is that such a $g$ exists and is unique.

Comment: But what is the explicit form of g?

Comment: To construct $g$, you can do just the same as in the demonstration of the theorem. Take a sequence $g_n$ of functions such that $\int_A g_n\, d\mu \leq \mu(A)$, and such that $\int_X g_n\, d\mu \rightarrow \mu(X)$. Now, $g = \limsup g_n$. This is as explicit as it gets for me... :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I think your application of the transformation formula for $\mu$ is wrong! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure

Comment: @math12: I think you are right. The fix is easier then it seems... I will fix it. Thank you.

Comment: I do not come along with showing that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Sorry! You don't have to show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. The $\lambda$ should be $\sigma$-finite!!! My mistake! Sorry.

Comment: But $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finte, because it's the Lebesgue-measure.

Comment: @math12: Yes. I would even change the statement being proved. Instead of assuming $\lambda$ is Lebesgue, you could simply assume it is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: But in order to apply Radon-Nikodým isn't it necessary that $\mu$ is a signed measure or a $\sigma$-finite measure?

Comment: @math12: Given that $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite, I think $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite iff $g$ is finite almost surely. Also, $\mu$ is finite iff $g$ is in $L^1_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Can you explain why to your opinion $\mu$ is finite? Because $\mu(\mathbb{R})=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\, d\lambda\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert f\rvert\, d\lambda<\infty$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12751/discussion-between-andre-caldas-and-math12)

Comment: In the case of positive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, $\sigma$-finitess of $\nu$ is sufficient to ensure the existence of a density for $\mu$ w.r.t. $\nu$. Nothing is required for $\mu$, excepted positivity. This is an easy consequence of the usual Radon-Nykodim theorem. You can find a proof in Neveu, "Mathematical foundations of the calculus of probability", for instance.

Answer (score -1):

$ \int_{T^{-1}(A)}fd\lambda = \int_{A}dT\#(f\lambda) $ where $ T\#\nu $ is the push-forward measure of $ \nu $ by $T$. Then by change of variable you can find that
$ T\#(f\lambda) = f\circ T^{-1}|det(DT\circ T^{-1})|^{-1}\lambda $.

Let
$P_T(f) = f(T^{-1})|det(DT\circ T^{-1})|^{-1} $, clearly linear in f. Not sure this proves uniqueness and you need some more assumptions on T, such as derivability, but perhaps this might help you.

Comment: I think this does not work... because f.e. there is nowhere said that T is differentiable...

Comment: Yep my thought too, but since you said you had no idea at all maybe being able to see what the operator looks like under different assumptions could help you find some ideas ;)

Comment: But maybe you should have put this in a comment, now everybody things the answer is alredy given..

Comment: OK, will do next time !